# jcrop - round selection results

Tags: php, jquery, jcrop

I am trying to use jcrop however being new to jquery I am a bit perplexed in how to use the "round" function in the jquery function.

As I submit the results via PHP variables and they are used in on screen display in jquery , I would prefer to round them as acquired in jquery thereby assuring consistency in jquery and php. I would not want one to round up while the other rounds down. It looks like the defailt behavior of round is to round to nearest integer and that is fine.

My script current (with some php)

```
<?php
$boxwidth=500;
$boxheight=500;
?>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#cropbox').Jcrop({ boxWidth: <?php echo $boxwidth;?>, boxHeight: <?php echo $boxheight;?> });
});


$(document).ready(function()
{
// Update co-ordinates
    function updateCoordinates(cropbox)
    {
        $("#crop_x").val(cropbox.x);
        $("#crop_y").val(cropbox.y);
        $("#width").val(cropbox.w);
        $("#height").val(cropbox.h);
    }



    // Attach jCrop
    $("#cropbox").Jcrop({
    <?php echo (isset($_POST['aspect_ratio']) ? 'aspectRatio: ' . ((float)$_POST['width'] / (float)$_POST['height']) . ',' : ''); ?>
        onChange: updateCoordinates,
        onSelect: updateCoordinates
    });
});
-->
</script>
```

I am unfamiliar with this type of code and do not know how to round the results. I am not displaying the actual image file rather a browser resized version of it and often get results like 100.3394567892 x 100.544222 pixels, which would result in an image of 100x101. I know it will not be "pixel accurate" and I may have to settle for 99x99 when I want 100x100 but the size displayed would be true to the end result, and I would eliminate displaying the image size with 10 digits beyond the decimal.

Answer (score 0):

after some attempts at figurinfrom code in OP I applied the folling changes
from

```
    $("#crop_x").val(cropbox.x);
    $("#crop_y").val(cropbox.y);
    $("#width").val(cropbox.w);
    $("#height").val(cropbox.h);
```

to

```
    $("#crop_x").val(Math.round(cropbox.x));
    $("#crop_y").val(Math.round(cropbox.y));
    $("#width").val(Math.round(cropbox.w));
    $("#height").val(Math.round(cropbox.h));
```